# How to dynamically create Menu Items from json in reactjs?

Tags: django, python-3.x, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material UI and everything in the examples is static. Is there something to see for a JSON example?

Comment: replace that static part with a loop on json and create the menu elements dynamically, like this: `[values here].map(el => <Menu />)`

Comment: Thanks. this is helpful. I'm still new to it..do you have some more detailed example?

Comment: can you post the json from which you want to create menu items?

Comment: {"ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "6220D8E", "HostId": "6IrP0tqhAIShLt2zsCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"x-amz-id-2": "6IrP0tqhx/nDOH0p4=", "x-amz-request-id": "62AC918E", "date": "Sun, 13 May 2018 17:19:44 GMT", "content-type": "application/xml", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "server": "AmazonS3"}, "RetryAttempts": 0}, "Buckets": [{"Name": "elasticb-east-1-6532860766", "CreationDate": "2014-09-01T16:58:41Z"}, {"Name": "elasticbeanstalk-860766", "CreationDate": "2015-10-06T00:24:57Z"}, {"Name": "elasticbeansta", "CreationDate": "2015-10-02T17:37:19Z"}], "Owner": {"DisplayName": "", "ID": "b4bf

Comment: Just buckets: name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
"Buckets": [
    {"Name": "elasticb-east-1-6532860766", "CreationDate": "2014-09-01T16:58:41Z"},
    {"Name": "elasticbeanstalk-860766", "CreationDate": "2015-10-06T00:24:57Z"},
    {"Name": "elasticbeansta", "CreationDate": "2015-10-02T17:37:19Z"}
]

<Menu>
    {
        this.state.Buckets.map((el,i) => (<MenuItem key={i} primaryText={el.Name} />))
    }
</Menu>
```

Assuming you will store the bucket values in the state variable.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: How does react know to make this iteration in HTML?

Comment: we don't write html with react, its jsx :), there we can write js in `{}`, i will suggest to check doc first, you will get answer of all your doubts. [**Doc**](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Comment: let me know if you have any doubt after that :)